# Insert function for linked list in descending order of insertion - only head node permited

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been tasked with creating a program in C that inserts user input into a simply linked list, but with the following constraints:

- Nodes have to be sorted in descending order;
- Only allowed to use the head node monitor (no tail node for monitoring allowed).

This is the current code for my insert function:

```
void insert(struct snode *node, struct snode *aux) {
    if (aux) {
        if (node->n >= monitor.head->n) {
            node->next = monitor.head;
            monitor.head = node;
            return;
        }
        if (node->n < aux->n) {
            node->next = aux->next;
            aux->next = node;
            return;
        } else
            insert(node, aux->next);
    }
}
```

The problem I got stuck in is: If I input, for exemple: `5` then `9` then `1`, the list will end up being sorted as `9` -> `1` -> `5` -> `NULL`, it should be `9` -> `5` -> `1` -> `NULL`. Just what am I missing here? Because I tried everything I could think of.

Here is the full program in case it helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* GLOBAL VARS */
struct snode {
    int n;
    struct snode *next;
};
struct smonitor {
    struct snode *head;
} monitor;

/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPING */
void insert(struct snode *node, struct snode *aux);
void search(int s, struct snode *aux);
struct snode *aloc(int p);
void print(struct snode *aux);
void readInputFile();

/* MAIN LOOP */
int main() {
    int p, s;
    int opt;
    _Bool endMain = 1;
    while (endMain == 1) {
        struct snode *aux = monitor.head;
        printf("Define Option:\n0-Exit\n1-Insert\n2-Search\n3-Print\n");
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        switch (opt) {
          case 0:
            endMain = 0;
            break;
          case 1:
            printf("Define node:\n");
            scanf("%d", &p);
            struct snode *node = aloc(p);
            if (monitor.head == NULL)
                monitor.head = node;
            else
                insert(node, aux);
            break;
          case 2:
            printf("Define search term:\n");
            scanf("%d", &s);
            search(s, aux);
            break;
          case 3:
            printf("List is:\n");
            print(aux);
            printf("[NULL]\n");
            break;
          case 4:
            readInputFile();
            break;
          default:
            printf("INVALID OPTION\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* FUNCTIONS */
void insert(struct snode *node, struct snode *aux) {
    if (aux) {
        if (node->n >= monitor.head->n) {
            node->next = monitor.head;
            monitor.head = node;
            return;
        }
        if (node->n < aux->n) {
            node->next = aux->next;
            aux->next = node;
            return;
        } else
            insert(node, aux->next);
    }
}

void search(int s, struct snode *aux) {
    if (aux) {
        if (s == aux->n)
            printf("HIT - Node %d found\n", aux->n);
        else
            search(s, aux->next);
    } else
        printf("NO HIT - Node not found\n");
}

struct snode *aloc(int p) {
    struct snode *node;
    node = (struct snode *)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    node->n = p;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void print(struct snode *aux) {
    if (aux) {
        printf("[%d]-", aux->n);
        print(aux->next);
    }
}

void readInputFile() {
     FILE *fp;
     int input;
     struct snode *p;
     struct snode *aux;

     fp = fopen("/home/user/inputFile.txt", "r");
     printf("Nodes added:\n");
     while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &input) != EOF) {
         p = aloc(input);
         aux = monitor.head;
         if (monitor.head == NULL)
             monitor.head = p;
         else
             insert(p, aux);
         printf("[%d]-", input);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide! :D

/*-------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------*/
After you guy's feedback and some tests i managed to get to a solution, probably not the best implementation of it and there are other answers with different implementations (which are very appreciated! :) ) down there, but here's the new version of that insert function, again, thank you all for the tips! :D

```
void insert (struct snode *node, struct snode *aux, struct snode *pre){
    if(aux){
        if(node->n >= monitor.head->n){
            node->next = monitor.head;
            monitor.head = node;
            return;
        }
        if((pre->n >= node->n) & (node->n >= aux->n)){
            pre->next = node;
            node->next = aux;
            return;
        }
        if((pre->n >= node->n) & (aux->next == NULL)){
            aux->next = node;
            return;
        }
        insert(node, aux->next, aux);
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I tried everything i could think of._": did you think of stepping through your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring due to this part of `insert()` code:

```
        if(node->n < aux->n){      // <=========
                node->next = aux->next;
                aux->next = node;
            ....
            ....
```

The sequence of insertion is `5`, `9` and `1`. When you insert `1`, at that time the linked list is

```
-------      -------
|  9  |----->|  5  |
-------      -------
```

the value of `node->n` is `1` and value of `aux->n` is `9`. So, the comparison of `if` condition is evaluated to `true`:

```
if(node->n < aux->n){
```

and the node with value `1` inserted right after node `9` and you are getting sequence `9`, `1` and `5`.

Comment: He's also not initializing `monitor.head` anywhere that I can see.

Comment: @MikeHolt the `monitor.head` is initialized in `main()` in the `switch` `case 1`.

Comment: @H.S. Thanks for the reply! Any ideas on how to make the function be sure that it is inserting the node in the proper place? I though of having a third argument that would be set as arg = aux, before setting aux = aux->next in the next function call, then modify that if statement to if((node->n > aux->n) & (node->n < arg->n)), i'll try this here but what do you think?

Comment: @RefriDeLagosta Yes passing `aux` as third argument should work. Roughly the `insert()` code would be, assume the name of third parameter of `insert()` function `prev` which will receive the `aux` value (the first and second parameter names not changed),  - `if (aux->n < node->n) { node->next = aux; if (prev) prev->next = node; if (aux == monitor.head) monitor.head = node;} else {insert(node, aux->next, aux);}`. Note that there is scope of improvement in your code. You can write it in much better way.

Comment: @MikeHolt: `monitor` is a global variable, its fields are initialized implicitly to the null value of their type, hence `monitor.head` **is** initialized to `NULL` before `main` starts.

Comment: @H.S. What code are you looking at? I see `if (monitor.head == NULL) monitor.head = node; else ...`, which references it prior to assigning it. It looks like OP is relying on the compiler to zero out the struct, or relying on sheer luck, hoping that there will be some zeros at that memory location upon program initialization.

Comment: @chqrlie Must be a language standard change that's new to me. I've been programming C for a few decades now and I'm used to initializing everything, global or otherwise.

Comment: @H.S.: `case 1` of the `main` `switch` is not an initialization, you just test `monitor.head` to special case the insertion of the first node. Why to you pass `aux` to the `insert` function since it must use `monitor` for another special case. You should instead pass the address of `monitor` and let `insert` handle all cases. This way you could make `monitor` a local variable.

Comment: @chqrlie Nevermind, I see that it dates back to C89, which is a couple years prior to when I started programming in C. I guess I've just been zeroing globals out needlessly all this time. Although, in fairness, the timing of it probably means that I've encountered several compilers that didn't conform to that yet at the time.

Comment: @MikeHolt: I'm afraid not, common variables have been initialized this way for a very long time, even before ANSI C. Some embedded systems software may be designed to nor perform this step, and obviously the startup code cannot assume anything, but hosted applications can rely on this implicit initialization. Of course, there are also a few non conforming systems out there...

Comment: @chqrlie Good to know. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @H.S Did it! I was trying to pull of a if(pre->n >= node->n >= aux->n) but that wasn't going through, so i made it use "&" instead then added the final if statement for bottom insertion. I'll post the whole code again on another answer. Thank you for very much for the tip! :D

Comment: @chqrlie In one of my previous comment, I have mentioned to OP - _"there is scope of improvement in your code. You can write it in much better way."_ and I deliberately left this task for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is incorrect in `insert`. Beyond this fis, you should not use a global variable `monitor` and letting `insert` and other functions modify it is confusing and defeats the purpose of passing the list as an argument.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* STRUCTURES */
struct snode {
    int n;
    struct snode *next;
};
struct smonitor {
    struct snode *head;
};

/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES */
void insert(struct snode *node, struct smonitor *mon);
void search(int s, struct smonitor *mon);
struct snode *aloc(int p);
void print(struct smonitor *mon);
void readInputFile(struct smonitor *mon);
int flush(void);

/* MAIN LOOP */
int main() {
    int p, s;
    int opt;
    struct smonitor monitor = { NULL };
    _Bool endMain = 0;

    while (!endMain) {
        printf("Define Option:\n0-Exit\n1-Insert\n2-Search\n3-Print\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &opt) != 1)
            break;
        switch (opt) {
          case 0:
            endMain = 1;
            break;
          case 1:
            printf("Define node:\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &p) != 1) {
                flush();
                break;
            }
            struct snode *node = aloc(p);
            if (node == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "allocation failure\n");
                break;
            }
            insert(node, &monitor);
            break;
          case 2:
            printf("Define search term:\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &s) != 1) {
                flush();
                break;
            }
            search(s, &monitor);
            break;
          case 3:
            printf("List is:\n");
            print(&monitor);
            break;
          case 4:
            readInputFile(&monitor);
            break;
          default:
            printf("INVALID OPTION\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* FUNCTIONS */

int flush(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

void insert(struct snode *node, struct smonitor *mon) {
    struct node *aux;
    if (mon->head == NULL || node->n > mon->head->n) {
        node->next = mon->head;
        mon->head = node;
        return;
    }
    aux = mon->node
    while (aux->next && node->n <= aux->next->n) {
        aux = aux->next;
    }
    node->next = aux->next;
    aux->next = node;
}

void search(int s, struct smonitor *mon) {
    struct snode *aux = mon->head;
    while (aux) {
        if (s == aux->n) {
            printf("HIT - Node %d found\n", aux->n);
            return;
        }
        aux = aux->next;
    }
    printf("NO HIT - Node not found\n");
}

struct snode *aloc(int p) {
    struct snode *node;
    node = (struct snode *)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    if (n != NULL) {
        node->n = p;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void print(struct smonitor *mon) {
    struct snode *aux = mon->head;
    while (aux) {
        printf("[%d]-", aux->n);
        aux = aux->next;
    }
    printf("[NULL]\n");
}

void readInputFile(struct smonitor *mon) {
     FILE *fp;
     int input;

     fp = fopen("/home/user/inputFile.txt", "r");
     if (fp == NULL) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file /home/user/inputFile.txt\n");
         return;
     }
     printf("Nodes added:\n");
     while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &input) == 1) {
         struct snode *p = aloc(input);
         if (p == NULL) {
             fprintf(stderr, "\nallocation failure\n");
             break;
         }
         insert(p, mon);
         printf("[%d]-", input);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The insertion logic, 
only guarantee that the logic is correct, not the optimal implementation. If the link is long, it will not work with recursion.

1. If aux is head and node is larger than aux, node is inserted on the
   head
2. If aux->next is null, node is inserted at the end
3. If node is larger than aux->next, node should be inserted between
   aux and aux->next
4. Otherwise put aux backward

Change the insert function to

```
void insert(struct snode *node, struct snode *aux)
{
    if (aux) {
        if(aux == monitor.head && node->n >= aux->n) {
            node->next = monitor.head;
            monitor.head = node;
        } else if (!aux->next) {
            aux->next = node;
        } else if(node->n >= aux->next->n) {
            node->next = aux->next;
            aux->next = node;
        } else {
            insert(node, aux->next);
        }
    }
}
```